# Group by with column heading

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame where I am trying to get the median values of a column titled RSRP.

```
df = pd.read_excel('Carriers.xlsx')
car_grp=df.groupby(['CARRIER'])
df4=car_grp['RSRP'].median()
df4.to_excel('Median.xlsx',index=False)
```

This is the input file:
[image]

I am trying to get this output as xlsx file:

[image]

Comment: remove `index=False` when use `to_excel`

Answer (score 1):

To calculate `median` by using `group_by` try to use below code:

```
output_df = df.groupby(["CARRIER"])["RSRP"].median().reset_index()
```

Another option to set the column name is to use `pandas.DataFrame.agg`:

```
output_df = df.groupby(["CARRIER"]).agg(RSRP_MEDIAN=('RSRP', 'median')).reset_index()
```

After that, you can save output to xlsx

```
output_df.to_excel("output_df.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: thanks, what should be the code if I would like to add Title "Median" in the median column?

Comment: Try this solution `output_df = df.groupby(["CARRIER"]).agg(MEDIAN=('RSRP', 'median')).reset_index()`